# Can I use this.userId in Meteor.onConnection()?

Tags: facebook, meteor

I am building a mobile application where my users can connect using `accounts-facebook`.

What I would like to do is refreshing their list of friends that use the app when they are logging in (is this a good way to keep this list up to date ?) or when they are connecting

I built something like this :

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
  myFunctionToRefreshFriendLists()
});
Meteor.onConnection(function(conn) {
  if (this.userId) {
    myFunctionToRefreshFrindLists();
  }
}
```

But this returns me "undefined", even when the user is connected. I know there is a problem using "this.userId" (*this* here does not seem relevant to me) but I do not know what to do ?

Any help appreciated, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Meteor.onConnection, as it will run every time a user starts a new connection. This can happen frequently depending on the stability of their connection; instead use Accounts.onLogin:

```
Accounts.onLogin(function(user){
  console.log(user.user._id)
});
```

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_onlogin

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed !